# Rails API expiration for user auth token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, backend

I build an Rest API with rails. And I want to implement an expiration for the token. How does it works ?
I don't to implement devise because I don't need that really.
I just want when I create an user he received an token a refresh token.
So it's not really oauth because there are not 3rd party using the api.

```
This is my user model.
    require 'securerandom'
      class User
      field :auth_token, type: String
      field :name, type: String
      field :phone, type: String
      field :image, type: String

      #Generate URLS for different image sizes...
       def as_json(options)
        json = super
        self.image.styles.each do | format |
          json = json.merge({"image_"+format[0].to_s => self.image(format[0])})
        end
        json
      end

      private
        def set_auth_token
          return if auth_token.present?
          self.auth_token = generate_auth_token
        end

        def generate_auth_token
          SecureRandom.hex(90)  
        end

      end
```

So simple auth with a simple generated token works. But I think with an expiration token is more secure. Of course the connection is over SSL.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

    def current_user
        @current_user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end


protected

    def authenticate
      authenticate_token || authentication_request
    end


    def authenticate_token
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      User.where(auth_token: token).first
      end
    end

    def authentication_request(controller, realm)
      controller.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
      controller.__send__ :render, :text => "HTTP Token: Access denied.\n", :status => :unauthorized
    end

    def request_http_token_authentication(realm = "Application")
      self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Token realm="#{realm.gsub(/"/, "")}")
      render :json => {:error => "HTTP Token: Access denied."}, :status => :unauthorized
    end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you generate the token, save the time you'd like it to expire:

```
class User
  field :auth_token, type: String
  field :token_expiry, type: Time

  def set_auth_token
    return if auth_token.present? && token_expiry > Time.now
    self.auth_token = generate_auth_token
    self.token_expiry = Time.now + 1.day
  end
```

Then when you check the token, check the expiry too:

```
def authenticate_token
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    user = User.where(auth_token: token).first
    user if user.token_expiry > Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you ! For your answer :) And how it works with refresh token ? Because I want if the token is expired the user received a new one ? So I want to create 2 tokens one auth token and one refresh token. The refresh token is needed to get a new token ?:/

Comment: You can refresh the token however you like - if you want a second token the user has to exchange, build it.

Comment: Thank you okay it's from secure perspective better to hide the token when to render it ?

Comment: Who are you trying to hide it from? There's nowhere you can put it that the user can't access with the right effort. Just make sure you're using HTTPS so no one else can see it in transit, and keep it out of the URL if you don't want a naive user copy/pasting it.

Comment: Yes of course but with an man in the middle attack is possible

Comment: If you're getting MITMd, you already have far larger problems.

Comment: So you mean I have to use certificate pinning ?

Comment: It sounds like you're struggling trying to find direction. Do some reading to figure out what you want or need, then come back to SO with another specific question when you encounter a problem.